# How to detect when a Java Swing scroll bar is at or near the bottom of the bar?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm working on a program that needs a sort of spreadsheet built into it. I'm using a JTable for a spreadsheet and I'm going to enclose that in a scrollable window, but spreadsheets are typically infinite, and the only way I could think to do that is make it such that when the user has scrolled to the bottom (or NEAR the bottom) of the spreadsheet, it adds like 20 new rows.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: check out this link for a good question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Spreadsheets are not infinite. :)

Comment: Ok, I guess not infinite, but so large that for all intents and purposes, they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `AdjustmentListener` to scroll bars. Check out below demonstration.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ScrollPaneEvents
{
  private static final float THRESHOLD = 0.9f;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("A\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF\nG\nH\nI\nJ\nK\nL\nM\nN\nO\nP\nQ\nR\nS\nT\nU\nV\nW\nX\nY\nZ\n");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
      {
        int maxValue = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum() - scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getVisibleAmount();
        int currentValue = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
        float fraction = (float) currentValue / (float) maxValue;

        if (fraction > THRESHOLD)
        {
          System.out.println("Scroll bar is near the bottom");
        }
      }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```